# Can only ssh as centos user

Tags: centos, ssh

I am ssh'ing to a CentOS 7.2 server using public key authentication (from a Mac OS X bash session). I can successfully ssh using the centos user to the remote box, using the PEM key I have with the `-i` argument when specifying `centos@remotehost`.

I would like to ssh with another user that exists on the remote host. I don't see any AllowUser or DenyUser rules in the sshd_config on the remote host. When I run `ssh -i mykey.pem -v auser@remotehost` I get `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

Both users exist in `/etc/passwd` on the remote host. I don't understand why only the centos user can successfully ssh. In `/var/log/secure` on the remote host I see `localhost sshd[19206]: error: AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys returned status 1`.

The thing is, I see that same message for *successful* logins as well, in which case it's followed by `Accepted publickey for centos . . .`

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you configure `authorized_keys` for the `auser` on the remote host?

Answer (score 0):

I accepted an answer here, it looks like it was deleted. `auser` had a home directory had a mode that ssh didn't like (because the home directory also contains the `.ssh` directory). When I changed the mode to `700` the connection with `auser` worked as expected.